# Why are ps1 scripts associated with Notepad by default?

Tags: windows, powershell

In Windows, whenever I click on a `.bat`, `.cmd` or `.vbs` script (Batch and VBScript) file, they get executed by their individual engines (Command Prompt and windows script host).

So, why is the powershell extension `.ps1` associated with Notepad by default, instead of Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Microsoft tried to design PowerShell as secure by default. Although Microsoft doesn't seem to have explicitly stated this anywhere, this restriction was probably meant to prevent users from being tricked into executing and spreading malicious scripts.

There is a good description of why this could be dangerous [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/204166/how-to-configure-windows-to-work-with-powershell-scripts-more-easily):

> PowerShell is effectively the command shell and scripting language that’s intended to replace CMD and batch scripts on Windows systems. As such, a PowerShell script can pretty much be configured to do anything you could do manually from the command line. That equates to making practically any change possible on your system, up to the restrictions in place on your user account. So, if you could just double-click a PowerShell script and run it with full Administrator privileges, a simple one-liner like this could really wreck your day: `Get-ChildItem "$env:SystemDrive\" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`
> ***DO NOT run the above command!***
>
> ...
>
> What could be worse is, instead of getting a script that just trashes their file system, your friend might be tricked into running one that downloads and installs a keylogger or remote access service.

In practice though, powershell code can be executed through a `.bat` file by simply passing the code as a commandline argument to powershell. So PowerShell now relies on [AMSI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-portal) (Anti-Malware Scan Interface) to block malicious scripts. For some unexplained reason, the original restriction has been left in place.

Comment: OK, understand powershell can execute highly vulnerable scripts, but still we can't delete the files in winDir without having ownership on them, and here batch file can also do this. So why .bat or .vbs scripts have not been associated with notepad or any other text editors?

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan The original script engines weren't designed with security in mind. A lot of people already relied on .vbs and .bat files so Microsoft couldn't just suddenly change the file associations for them for backward compatibility reasons or it would break their setups. For example, if someone had placed a .bat file in the startup directory, the file would stop working as intended and cause a lot of inconvenience.